# Is it pointer constant or variable constant?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the difference between const int*, const int * const, int const *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-int-const)
>   [constant pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407041/constant-pointer)

Is there any difference between these two statements?

```
void * const sam;
```

and

```
void const *sam;
```

Comment: Is it just me, or are the people using `void *sam` syntax more prone to ask this question than the ones who use `void* sam`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void * const sam;
```

the pointer is read-only. The qualifier is after the `*`.

```
void const *sam;
```

the *pointee* is read-only.  The qualifier is before the `*`.

Answer (score 0):

```
const int * Constant
```

declares that Constant is a variable pointer to a constant integer and

```
int const * Constant
```

is an alternative syntax which does the same, whereas

```
int * const Constant
```

declares that Constant3 is constant pointer to a variable integer and

Source:

http://duramecho.com/ComputerInformation/WhyHowCppConst.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

After changing `void` to `int`

```
int * const sam;
sam = NULL; /* invalid */
*sam = 42; /* valid */
```

or

```
int const *sam;
sam = NULL; /* valid */
*sam = 42; /* invalid */
```